# Rails validation on a joint table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have following models:

Product (id, name):

```
    has_many :prices
```

Product_price (id, product_id, price): *The thing is that each product can have different prices*

```
    belongs_to :product
```

Subscription (id, name):

```
    has_many :subscription_price_sets,
             foreign_key: :subscription_price_set_id,
             inverse_of: :subscription
    has_many :product_prices, through: :subscription_price_sets
```

Subscription_price_set (id, product_price_id, subscription_id):

```
    belongs_to :subscription,
               foreign_key: :subscription_id
    belongs_to :product_price,
               foreign_key: :product_price_id
```

How do I validate it, so that for a given subscription it's impossible to have a product with two different prices?

For example:

I have two products: **Notebook** (id: 1) and **Pencil** (id: 2)
And their prices are:

Product_prices:

```
(id: 1, product_id: 1, price: 4)
(id: 2, product_id: 1, price: 12)
(id: 3, product_id: 1, price: 10)
(id: 4, product_id: 2, price: 3)
(id: 5, product_id: 2, price: 2)
```

And a Basic subscription:

```
(id: 1, name: "Basic")
```

Let's say I have Subscription_price_set:

```
(id: 1, product_price_id: 1, subscription_id: 1)
```

Now I should be able to create another `Subscription_price_set` with `subscription_id: 1`, but the only allowable product_price_ids should be id: 4 and id: 5.

Any hints on how to achieve that?

Comment: Checkout https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of with `scope` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a custom validation method in `Subscription_price_set` model, and it did the trick :)

```
validate :product_uniqness

private

def product_uniqness
  return unless subscription.product_prices.pluck(:product_id)
                         .include?(product_price.product_id)

  errors.add(:product_price_id, 'You can\'t add the same product twice')
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `scope` to make a uniqueness validation on multiple columns:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :subscription_id, scope: :product_price_id
```

However this does not actually guarantee uniqueness.

[image: Image courtesy of Thoughtbot]

To safeguard against race conditions you need to compliment the validation with a database index:

```
class AddIndexToSubscriptionPriceSets < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_index :subscription_price_sets, [:subscription_id, :product_price_id] , unique: true
  end
end
```

Your also using the `foreign_key` option all wrong. Rails is driven by convention over configuration and will derive the foreign key from the name of the association. You only ever need to specify `foreign_key` if the name of the association does not match.

```
belongs_to :subscription
belongs_to :product_price
```

On the `has_many` association it will actually cause an error:

```
has_many :subscription_price_sets,
         foreign_key: :subscription_price_set_id,
         inverse_of: :subscription
```

This will result in the following join

```
JOINS subscription_price_sets ON subscription_price_sets.subscription_price_set_id = subscriptions.id
```

Which of course will blow up as there is no such column. The foreign_key option on a has_many association is used to specify which column on the other table that corresponds to this table. All you really need is:

```
has_many :subscription_price_sets
```

Rails can also  deduce the inverse of an association based and you only need to specify when you are "going off the rails" and the names don't match up.